# Failed to monitor another Vm using zabbix agent

Tags: virtual-machine, zabbix, agent, zabbix-api

I'm trying to monitor a virtual machine from another.  have two ubuntu virtual machines one with the zabbix server and another with the zabbix agent.
but after setting up my agent by using my public ip i get this error :`Received empty response from Zabbix Agent at [192.168.x.x]. Assuming that agent dropped connection because of access permissions.`

in  `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd`  i changed my server to `server= 127.0.0.1,192.168.x.x`
and i turned off my firewall just in case.

My agent status:
[image]
If you are familiar please help
and /var/log/zabbix_agentd.log

[image]

Comment: See the logs of the client...

Comment: @KamilCuk you mean /var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log ?

Comment: No, I mean of _client_. I mean `systemctl status zabbix-agentd` or `journalctl -u zabbix-agentd` or whatever you did setup your client to log into.

Comment: @KamilCuk i updated my post with a screenshot

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. Post the text instead. Great, it's working - so `zabbix_get` works from server to the client?

Comment: @KamilCuk oh yeah sorry about the screen shot but I can't copy and past that's why. as for zabbix_get i wasn't capable of installing it unfortunately but I checked my agent log and I found failed to accept an incoming connection

Comment: Your file viewer is truncating the lines hiding error message. Use a different file viewer. Or just `cat`.

Comment: @KamilCuk failed to accept an incoming connection from "Ip of the server VM" rejected,  allowed hosts "Ip of the agent VM "

Comment: So you know - the remove address IP and that it's not allowed. So allow it. Add the server IP to `Server=` and in `ActiveServer=` in client configuration.

Comment: so i need to put the ip of the server not the agent

Comment: @KamilCuk It's working. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In logs you got:

> Failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "192.168.243.2" rejected, allowed hosts: "127.0.0.1,192.168.243.3"

The log itself tells you what host is trying to connect and what hosts are allowed :)

It's trying to connect x.x.x.2 and the allowed host in the config is x.x.x.3. Change agent config 192.168.243.2 to 192.168.243.3 +restart and it should work